# Python3 with urllib and accent

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-3.x, urllib

I try to access an URL with an accent but it didn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?city=Lévis&format=json")
content = response.read()
print(content)
```

When I execute this code I have this error in return

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I try this

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?city=Lévis&format=json".encode("UTF-8"))
```

But still an error

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Do you have any ideas where is my mistake ?

Comment: URLs [cannot contain arbitrary Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#List_of_allowed_URL_characters). You'll need to escape the offending character [in some way](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your query parameters, like @Cairnarvon said:

```
import urllib.parse

city = 'Lévis'
query = "city=%s&format=json" % (urllib.parse.quote(city),)
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?" + query)
```